# Jewel vendors in Mists of Pandaria?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I know that back in Burning Crusade, you could purchase some jewels from NPC's (in Honor Hold, for example) - of course, those were entry-level jewelry, because JC's would do the hard work. That was also true in Wrath of the Lich King and Cataclysm.

But I can't find anything like that in Mists of Pandaria.

Is there any Vendor (wether be with Gold, Honor, or Valor points) that sells gems for equipment? If so, where?

Comment: In MoP, if you're looking for the "cheaper" jewels then look to the auction house. They're a dime a dozen these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only recall various [common](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=19330) [gem](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=22227) [vendors](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=22225) in BC, greens in limited numbers from [Dealer Senzik](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=19538) in Netherstorm, and uncut epic gems from [Shaani](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=25950) on the Isle of Quel'Danas for Justice.

In Northrend, I recall the only gems you could purchase were uncut epic gems from [Harold Winston](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=32172), the Jewelry Vendor and [Legacy Justice Quartermasters](http://www.wowhead.com/search?q=Legacy+Justice+Quartermaster) in Dalaran and the major faction cities for Justice.

In Cataclysm, you can collect 2 types of raid tokens (Mote of Darkness from raid bosses, Essence of Corrupted Deathwing from Deathwing) that can redeemed from [Dasnurimi](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=58153) for Geodes containing containing uncut epic gems.

In Pandaria, the only uncut gems that can be directly purchased are the Jewelcrafter's Serpent's Eye (actually a rare gem that become a epic Jewelcrafters Facet after it is cut) in exchange for a Spirit of Harmony. As of this post, there are no epic gems available in the expansion (with the exception of the JC facet cuts) at the moment.

I believe that the only reason the common gem vendors were available in BC was because JC was only recently introduced back in BC. But since then Alchemists and Prospecting have made gems to be more easily available, so there is no need to have these "entry level" gem vendors.

They also removed Gem Honor Vendors when Cataclysm came out.

Comment: Exactly those vendors are the ones I'm referring too. I could just go with some gold and get those sockets filled (at least it was something, but still, of course, the JC's had the juicy stuff). I guess I gotta pay a visit to the AH, and I hope those aren't expensive as hell.